# A problem about circular transfromation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space with dimension $n$,$\mathscr A$ is linear transformation over $V$.

**Definition**:we say $\mathscr A $ is circular transformation if $∃ \alpha ∈V$ such that $\{\alpha,\cdots,\mathscr A^{n-1}(α) \}$ is a basis of $V$.

> problem:$\mathscr A $ is circular transformation iff for every linear transformation $\mathscr B $ which is commutative with $\mathscr A $,$∃f(x)∈F[x] $ such that $\mathscr B =f(\mathscr A) $.

*My attempt *:
$\Rightarrow$:Let $\mathscr B $ be such transformation,$\alpha $ be such vector. $\mathscr B(\beta)=\mathscr B (\sum_ {i=0}^{n-1} x_i \mathscr A^i(α))=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x_i \mathscr A^i \mathscr B(α) $.
Assume $\mathscr B(α)=f(\mathscr A)(α)$ then $\mathscr B(\beta)=\sum_ {i=0}^{n-1} x_i \mathscr A^i f(\mathscr A)(α) =f(\mathscr A)(\sum _{i=0}^{n-1} x_i \mathscr A^i(α))=f(\mathscr A)(\beta)$.

so $\mathscr B=f(\mathscr A)$

$\Leftarrow$:i don't know how to do it! I try assume $\mathscr A$ is not circular transformation amd then to find a linear transformation $\mathscr B$ which is commutative with $\mathscr A$.but i I can't go on doing it.

Comment: How do $n-1$ vectors give a basis for an $n$-dimensional vector space? Is this "circular" a translation from another language? Maybe *circulant* is the right word.

Comment: You are on the wrong track for the converse. It's actually totally easy. If $B=f(A)$, then $A$ and $B$ always commute. No hypotheses on $A$ whatsoever.

Comment: Does [this](https://planetmath.org/proofofcyclicvectortheorem) help you?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin sorry,I don't understand what you mean